# Tight binding model, get dispersion relation in crystal

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, tight-binding

I know the theory of tight binding model but don't know how to apply them in the real lattice

[image]

Comment: How far have you gotten? Could you show your work? The trick is to right down the tight-binding Hamiltonian in real space and to Fourier transform using $\bra{j A} = \sqrt{1/N} \Sigma_\vec{k} e^{-i \vec{k} \dot \vec{R_j^A}}\bra{\vec{k}A}$

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ above should read $|j \, A \rangle = \sqrt{1/N} \Sigma_{\vec{k}} \exp^{-i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{R}_j^A}| \vec{k} \, A \rangle$, apologies

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail 

Comment: I'd be happy to answer specific questions. Explaining my previous comment further: Fourier transform's are used to go from real space to reciprocal space and vice versa, in this case from position to momentum space. This is very useful here to get rid of the sums e.g. $\Sigma_j$ in the tight binding Hamiltonian from summing over unit cells (and neighbours to units cells). This is done by creating delta functions from multiplying oscillatory parts of Fourier transforms together.

Comment: I'd suggest finding the unit cell of graphene in the diagram above, write down the direct lattice vectors in the $(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$ basis, carefully figure out the tight-binding Hamiltonian in real space (taking into account nearest neighbour hopping from atoms outside your unit cell as well) and follow your derivation for the dispersion relation of electrons in a square lattice as inspiration.